# Crontab error while trying to run a rake task - Using whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, cron, rake-task, whenever

I have created a simple rake task. I am trying to use https://github.com/javan/whenever/ gem to run this task once a day. However, no tasks are being fired.

In my /var/mail/* file,

```
From: root@Gupta (Cron Daemon)
To: shubham@Gupta
Subject: Cron <shubham@Gupta> /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/shubham/Desktop/rails_apps/crispics && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake update_time_elapsed --silent'
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ANSI_X3.4-1968
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/shubham>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=shubham>
Message-Id: <20120720180401.E2D7AD4092D@Gupta>
Date: Fri, 20 Jul 2012 23:34:01 +0530 (IST)

tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
```

I have bundler installed in my system, and if I type the command from crontab to command prompt, task is fired.

Answer (score 0):

Run this in your project app

```
bundle update
```